# Create a custom selection of parameters

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a method that requires a parameter to distinguish between a few different scenarios. I could just pass on a string and hope that I (or whoever will use the class in future) will use one of the recognized commands. I would rather have a construct like this:

method declaration:

```
myMethod(myOption opt){ ... }
```

and the call should look like:

```
myMethod(myOption.option1);
```

in the method I should be able to do this:

```
if (opt == myOption.option1){ ... }
```

I believe this is the way the Message Box works, when I pass on the button or icon configuration.

I have experimented a lot and searched a lot, but I didn't find anything. Maybe that is because I have not found the correct combination of keywords to feed to google.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean that you want to invoke method by random number of parameters or invoke it by different types of constructors, I didn't understand your question !

Comment: I want to invoke the method with a single parameter. And the value of this parameter has to be one of a given number of possibilities. It is exactly what RJ Lohan showed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wrongly understand your question, don't miss to tick RJ's as a right answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a restricted set of available parameters, then an enum is probably the most suitable argument type to your method. So, create an enum to pass as your parameter;

```
public enum MyOption
{
    Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3,
}

public void MyMethod(MyOption option)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        case MyOption.Option1:
            // do stuff
            return;
        case MyOption.Option2:
            // do stuff
            return;
        case MyOption.Option3:
            // do stuff
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another question to that: Can I attach properties to the options? In my case each option represents a longer text. It would be cool to be able to use it as option.Text (or option.myProperty in general) inside of MyMethod(MyOption option).

Comment: If your options have more context than just being 'options' perhaps you need to use a class or struct. If the context is limited, perhaps you can attribute your enum values with a DescriptionAttribute and read that in your code.

Comment: Do you happen to have any tutorials/examples for how to wrap that in a class/struct? Or can you provide keywords which might help me find anything on that? My search so far has come back empty.

Comment: I'm sure you can find something with google. If you get stuck, ask another question here. Comments aren't appropriate for endless feedback cycles.